# How to write a Linux Top like console program in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

The `top` program keep updating the status every few seconds. It seems to me that the program doesn't repaint(clears and then print) the screen each time. How to do that ?

I'm actually writing a small console program that retrieve data from the web and then update it to the user.

Comment: A lot of Linux console tools that refresh the screen are built on top of something like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html). I have absolutely no idea how you would do that in Haskell,

Comment: You should also check the implementation of top itself to see how it gathers the information to display. http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/tools/perf/builtin-top.c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to use the Haskell bindings for the `ncurses` library:

- [hscurses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hscurses-1.4.1.2)
- [ncurses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses)
- [nanocurses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/nanocurses): This currently seems to be  unmaintained.

Another good option seems to be [vty-ui](http://jtdaugherty.github.io/vty-ui/). It also has a good amount of [documentation](http://jtdaugherty.github.io/vty-ui/manuals/vty-ui-users-manual-1.6.1.pdf) with it.

Comment: vty-ui seems great. But it depends on the unix package. Can it run on windows ?

Comment: @osager Sorry, I'm not sure about it. Their development seems to be quite active. I guess you can ping the developers and let us also know.

Comment: Finally i've settled on the ansi-terminal package. It is windows compatible